# shared JMS Connection does not established with .jar file, but with eclipse project

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms

shared JMS Connection does not established with .jar file, but with eclipse project.

**Getting below log when I am running through Jar**
Oct 24, 2016 7:01:28 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup start
INFO: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
Oct 24, 2016 7:01:29 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose

**Getting below log when I am running through Eclipse Maven project**
INFO: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
Oct 24, 2016 7:03:51 PM **org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory initConnection
INFO: Established shared JMS Connection: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection@56620197**
message.getJMSMessageID()...ID:414d5120514d20202020202020202020fca40d5820021702
xml....Test
Oct 24, 2016 7:03:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the issue, some web sphere MQ jar was not present in lib folder when I am creating executable jar file.